# How to get the contribution of each features with a datashape (35087, 15, 103)?

Tags: python, keras

I discovered recently a very nice github repository called [SHAP](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) written in Python and JavaScript. It can be used to explain the output of any machine learning model. You can see a good video [here](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/344) which explain well the library.

Inside a classification problem written in python, I discover I can have a little problem to use this library.

**EXPLANATION:**

I use exactly 103 features to modelize three labels described by -1, 0 and 1.
All my features are very well defined and all of them have a title associated. The problem I have is I am not passing 103 features at each unity. I am passing `103*15` features at each unity of time, i.e 103 features for the current time `t_0` and the same features for the times `t_-1, ..., t_-14`. The shape of my train dataset is `(35087, 15, 103)` where the first argument represents 35087 seconds.

Here is an obvious [example](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/notebooks/deep_explainer/Keras%20LSTM%20for%20IMDB%20Sentiment%20Classification.ipynb) how I might use it :

```
import shap

# we use the first 100 training examples as our background dataset to integrate over
explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(model, x_train[:100])

# explain the first 10 predictions
# explaining each prediction requires 2 * background dataset size runs
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(x_test[:10])

# init the JS visualization code
shap.initjs()

# transform the indexes to words
import numpy as np
words = imdb.get_word_index()
num2word = {}
for w in words.keys():
    num2word[words[w]] = w
x_test_words = np.stack([np.array(list(map(lambda x: num2word.get(x, "NONE"), x_test[i]))) for i in range(10)])

# plot the explanation of the first prediction
# Note the model is "multi-output" because it is rank-2 but only has one column
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value[0], shap_values[0][0], x_test_words[0])
```

Something I would like to get is simply

[image]

How to deal with the features at time t_-1, ..., t_-14 to get the contribution of each feature?

**UPDATE**

Here is an update of what I tried :

So initially, I have `103` features and `3` labels. `X_train.shape` is `(35087, 15, 103)` and `X_test.shape` is `(11696, 15, 103)`.

```
explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(Model.model, X_train[:100])
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test[:10])
```

Here `shap_values` seems to be a list of three arrays of shape `(10, 15, 103)`.

```
X_test_flatten = X_test.flatten()
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test_flatten, features_names=FEATURES)
```

From there I got the error `*** IndexError: index 40 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 15`

Could anyone help me to get `summary_plot` with the above information?

Comment: What kind of model are you using? Is the confusion matrix for the testing data?

Comment: That is interesting but because your are using the test data, it seems this is likely an example of overfitting to the training data. Do the same general results hold when you repeat the training and testing?

Comment: Is your data split into sequence length series overlapping in training set?